# Parameters of AsyncTask in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to understand AsyncTask in Android. I can't understand how do we pass parameters. In this code :

```
 protected class AsyncLogin extends AsyncTask<String, JSONObject, Boolean> {
        String userName = null;

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            RestAPI api = new RestAPI();
            boolean userAuth = false;
            try
            {
                JSONObject jsonObj = api.UserAuthentication(params[0], params[1]);
                JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
                userAuth = parser.parseUserAuth(jsonObj);
                userName = params[0];

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.d("AsyncLogin", e.getMessage());
            }

            return  userAuth;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Please wait...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected  void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
        {
            if(result) {
                Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UserDetailsActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("username", userName);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Not valid username/password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

I can't understand why do we use `<String, JSONObject, Boolean>`  in

```
protected class AsyncLogin extends AsyncTask<String, JSONObject, Boolean>
```

What do String, JSONObject and Boolean refer to? Can you explain it to me? Thanks.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AsyncTask (Type1, Type2, Type3) uses argument types:

- **Type1** is the type of argument you pass when you call [execute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute(Params...)) (received in [doInBackground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground(Params...)))
- **Type2** is the type of the argument you pass to [onProgressUpdate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate(Progress...)) when you call [publishProgress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress(Progress...)).
- **Type3** is the type of argument you pass to [onPostExecute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)), which is what you return from `doInBackground`.

Answer (score 1):

Asynch Task implementation allows you one type parameter as argument. But you can pass it more type parameters, by declaring one parameterized constructor to it. 
e.g.

```
class YourAsynchTask extends AsyncTask<ArgumentObject, ProgressObject, ResultObject> {

......

ObjectType1 argument1;
ObjectType2 argument2;
ObjectType3 argument3;

YourAsynchTask(ObjectType1 arg1, ObjectType2 arg2, ObjectType3 arg3) {
argument1 = arg1;
argument2 = arg2;
argument3 = arg3;
    } 


   // rest of the method of your asynch task like doInBackground, etc.
}
```

You can call this type of asynch task like this :

```
new YourAsynchTask(arg1, arg2, arg3).execute(argumentObjet);
```